MD5CryptoServiceProvider obsoleto
Estoy implementando esta interfaz y al usar MD5CryptoServiceProvider dice que está obsoleto y que usa Create.
Soy nuevo en este tema.
¿Cómo podría hacer para reemplazar al MD5?
Muchas gracias de antemano por su valiosa ayuda.
Saludos
public static string obtenermd5(string valor)
{
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider x=new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] data=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valor);
    data=x.ComputeHash(data);
    string resp = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        resp += data[i].ToString("x2").ToLower();
        return resp;
    }
}


Estoy usando .Net 8

Encontré el siguiente código que, al parecer, es lo mismo y soluciona mi problema.
 public static string GetMD5Hash2(string valor)
 {
     System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 obtenermd5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
     byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(valor);
     byte[] encoded = obtenermd5.ComputeHash(data);
     string resp = string.Empty;
     for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
         resp += data[i].ToString("x2").ToLower();
     return resp;
 }


return Convert.ToHexString(encoded);  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tohexstring?view=net-8.0

En mi opinión no deberías usar Encoding.Default sino uno en concreto como UTF8. Encoding.Default puede variar entre sistemas operativos, versiones de .NET etc. Así que podrías obtener valores diferentes del MD5 hash según las circunstancias.

Yo te propongo el siguiente método:
static string GetMD5Hash1(ReadOnlySpan<char> chars)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        Span<byte> utf8Bytes = stackalloc byte[Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(chars)];
        int count = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chars, utf8Bytes);
        Span<byte> hash = stackalloc byte[md5.HashSize / 8];
        md5.TryComputeHash(utf8Bytes, hash, out int written);
        Debug.Assert(written == hash.Length);
        return Convert.ToHexString(hash);
    }
}

La clase MD5 implementa IDisposable, así que debería estar en un using
He hecho una prueba de rendimiento usando BenchmarkDotNet comparándolo con el método:
public static string GetMD5Hash2(string valor)
{
    MD5 obtenermd5 =MD5.Create();
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valor);
    byte[] encoded = obtenermd5.ComputeHash(data);
    string resp = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        resp += data[i].ToString("x2").ToLower();
    return resp;
}

Y este es el resultado:
| Method     | Mean       | Error    | StdDev   | Gen0   | Gen1   | Allocated |
|----------- |-----------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|-------:|----------:|
| Benchmark1 |   324.9 ns |  5.98 ns |  5.59 ns | 0.0114 |      - |     216 B |
| Benchmark2 | 1,018.0 ns | 12.97 ns | 11.50 ns | 0.2537 | 0.0820 |    4792 B |

No sólo es más de tres veces más rápido, sino que además gasta bastante menos memoria
